# End-to-end tracking of ios push notification

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios9

How to know if APNS is successful to deliver the push notification or not?
How can I check if the device get the notification or not?

Comment: Please check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 here you will get simple push.php for checking push notification .

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder thanks for sharing the tutorial.